# Excel Regular Expression: Add Quote (") to Values in Two Columns

Tags: regex, vb.net, excel, vba, expression

So I have a CSV file with two columns that have items listed out like below:

[image]

The goal is to create a Excel VB code that will go through columns H and I, and add a quote (") to the beginning and end of each 6 digit group (e.g., H67100 into "H67100"). Additionally, the comma should be left alone.

I know the code is not complete as of yet, but this is what I have thus far. I think I am fine with the beginning part but after the match is found, I think my logic/syntax is incorrect. A little guidance and feedback is much appreciated:

```
Private Sub splitUpRegexPattern2()
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}(?=[,])"  
Dim regEx As New RegExp  
Dim strInput As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("H:I")

If strPattern <> "" Then
    strInput = Myrange.Value
    strReplace = """" & strInput & """"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

 End Sub
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
Function splitUpRegexPattern2 (Myrange As Range) as String

    Dim regEx As New RegExp  
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}(?=[,])"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = Myrange.Value
            strReplace = """" & strInput & """"     

            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = True
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
        simpleCellRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
    Else
        simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
    End If
End If

End FUNCTION
```

Adding example CSV file. [Download Sample CSV File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6FkhdDMjoXLWGdIUkYydUs2ZE0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Am I missing something, or do you not have a beginning to your `For` loop? I just see `Next` at the end.

Comment: Made a correction to what the code actually "is".

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following your logic entirely, but if you want to add quotation marks around `strInput`, you could just add `strInput = """" & strInput & """"`.

Comment: Yes, I only want to add a quote to begin and end of each character group. So is the updated code better then?

Comment: I'm not seeing where `strReplace` is actually being put back into your CSV file, but at least it should now contain the value of `strInput` with quotation marks around it.

Comment: Forgive me for sounding ignorant, but are you talking about "If regEx.test(strInput) Then...." statement? If so, can you give me an examples since I am new and I missing the point.

Comment: Possibly. However, that line of code is not included anywhere in the code in your question.

Comment: Ok. So I re-thought the code and made some updates to it. Based on what I read on several other posts, I should be able to use the above on a cell using the '=splitUpRegexPattern2(CELL) to get the output that I need.   Your thoughts and feedback is appreciated @TheEngineer.

Comment: @TheEnginner. I have uploaded a sample CSV file. Would you mind taking a look at it so I can get this code correct and working? I really really appreciate the help.

Comment: The file you uploaded was a .xlsx file. Will your code be in that file or a different file?

Comment: @theEngineer. The code will only be in that file that was provided.

Comment: Your question is tagged for vb.net, but your code appears to be VBA. Which would you like to use?

Comment: @theengineer VBA would be best. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you can get the values of each cell you are interested in.

There's no need to use RegEx in this case as your values appear to be simple comma-delimited data.

```
Public Const DOUBLE_QUOTE As String = Chr(34)
'''  
'''<summary>This function splits a string into an array on commas, adds quotes around each element in the array, the joins the array back into a string placing a comma between each element.</summary>
'''    
Public Function QuotedValues(ByVal input As String) As String
  Dim words As String() = input.Split(New Char() {","})
  Dim result As String = String.Empty

  words = (From w In words Select DOUBLE_QUOTE & w.Trim & DOUBLE_QUOTE).ToArray
  result = String.Join(", ", words)

  Return result
End Function
```

Comment: I am not sure how to properly run, so forgive me. I created a module and pasted the code you provided. I then tried to tie to a command box but I can't get it to run. Could you please explain how to run this?

Comment: I have uploaded a sample CSV file. Would you mind taking a look at it so I can get this code correct and working? I really really appreciate the help.